# Convergence of series of measurable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\phi_n\in\mathcal{L}^1(X,A,m)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\int_X|\phi_n|dm)<\infty$.

> How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(x)$ converges for every $x\in X\backslash N$ with $N\in A$ and $m(N)=0$?

**What I did:**
I defined 
$$   \phi(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(x) & : x \in X\backslash N\\
       0 & : x \in N
     \end{array}
   \right.$$
and showed that $\phi$ is $m$-integrable and $\int_X \phi dm=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_X\phi_ndm$.

> Is this enough to show convergence?

Comment: If $\phi$ is $m$-integrable, then it is finite almost everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing convergence and integrability from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_X |f_n| \, d \mu \lt \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535993/showing-convergence-and-integrability-from-sum-n-0-infty-int-x-f-n-d)

Comment: @Rigel Is being finite almost everywhere the same as convergence?

Comment: From your definition of $\phi$, if $\phi(x)$ is finite then the series is convergent at $x$.